# Antlr4 with Python 3 do not accept accented words

Tags: java, python, nlp, antlr, nltk

I'm trying to use Antlr4 with Python3 but the Antlr don't accept accented letters or others simbles like `!`.

I'm using the following grammar:

```
grammar GramaticaSintagmatica;
tokens {ART,ADJ,SUBS,VERB,PREP,PRON,CONJ,ADV,NUM,FABRICANTE}
WS : ( ’ ’ | ’\t’ | ’\r’ | ’\n’) {skip();} ;
fragment
LetrasAcentuadas :’á’|’à’|’â’|’ã’|’é’|’ê’|’í’|’ó’|’ô’|’õ’|’ú’|’ü’|’ç’|’À’|’Á’|’Â’|’Ã’|’É’|’Ê’|’Í'|’Ó’|’Ô’|’Õ’|’Ú’|’Ü’|’Ç’|’-’;
PALAVRA : (’a’..’z’|’A’..’Z’|LetrasAcentuadas)+ ;
INTS : ’0’..’9’+ (’.’ ’0’..’9’+)? ;
TERMINAL : ’.’|’?’|’!’|’;’;
VIRGULA : ’,’;
MODELO: ((’a’..’z’|’A’..’Z’) ’0’..’9’)+;
NAO : ’não’;
periodo :(oracao | . )*?;
oracao : sn_suj? nao_opc? sv sp_opc?| sp VIRGULA sn_suj? nao_opc? sv sp_opc?;
nao_opc: NAO;
sn_opc : sn;
sn : SUBS| det sa_opc? SUBS mod?;
sn_suj : ( SUBS (PREP? SUBS)* | PRON )| det sa_opc? SUBS (PREP? SUBS)* mod?;
det : pre_det? det_base pos_det?;
pre_det:;
det_base: ART| PRON| NUM;
pos_det: NUM| PRON;
mod : sa?| sp;
sp_opc : sp;
sp : PREP sn| ADV sp_opc?;
sa_opc : sa?;
sa : intens? ADJ ((CONJ | VIRGULA)? ADJ)* sp_opc?;
intens : ADV;
sv : VERB complemento;
complemento : sa_opc? sn_opc? sp_opc?;
```

And having errors like this:

> error<50>: GramaticaSintagmatica.g4:9:76: syntax error: '?' came as a complete surprise to me
>   error<50>: GramaticaSintagmatica.g4:9:84: syntax error: '-' came as a complete surprise to me
>   error<50>: GramaticaSintagmatica.g4:10:18: syntax error: '..' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
>   error<50>: GramaticaSintagmatica.g4:12:30: syntax error: '!' came as a complete surprise to me

I'm calling the antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar of this way:

> java -jar antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar GramaticaSintagmatica.g4 -o build_python -Dlanguage=Python3

Comment: Isn't the issue that you're using odd quotes `’` instead of the plain `'`?

Comment: this isn't `nltk` nor `python`, right?

Comment: Thanks Bart. It's just what you say.